# Copy from a cell of a column to a specific cell

Tags: vba, excel, cell

I am creating code for Excel to copy the content of a cell in the previous column to the next cell. The cell whose content I want to copy is green. But I need to search all the content in the whole workbook and in all the worksheets, because each green cell can be in a different column. My code is:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
frow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
fcol = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Column
Cells.UnMerge


Set wb = ActiveWorkbook


For Each sht In wb.Sheets
    For ncol = 1 To fcol
        For nrow = 1 To frow
            If Cells(nrow, ncol).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 128, 0) Then

                Cells(nrow, ncol - 1).Copy
                Cells(nrow, ncol).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Cells(nrow, ncol).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 128, 0)
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

But the problem is that in some sheets, the column with the green cell is empty and the code only gets all the columns with content (so fcol is totalColumnstoProcess-1) hence it does not copy the content to the cell that I want it to.

In summary: I want to go to all the worksheets in the workbook, detect where there are green cells and copy that content to the next column, same row.

Is there any other way to process all the content in the sheet?
Any idea why my code does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be a few problems with your code.

1. You need to define the search area of your worksheets on a sheet by sheet basis, so it needs to be inside your loop.
2. `UsedRange` is often to be avoided because it picks up formats as well as contents, but in your case it would work quite well. Your active area definition only picks up content.

The code below should help, but it'll need more thought if there are two adjacent green cells.

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Const GREEN As Long = 32768 'RGB(0, 128, 0)

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Define the range we want to interrogate
        Set rng = ws.UsedRange
        ' Check we have some cells to work with.
        If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Or rng.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color = GREEN Then
            For Each cell In rng
                'Find a green cell, making sure it isn't in Column "A"
                If cell.Column > 1 And cell.Interior.Color = GREEN Then
                    cell.Value = cell.Offset(, -1).Value2
                    'if you want to delete the old cell's value then uncomment the next line
                    cell.Offset(, -1).Value = vbNullString
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, shouldn't this work?

```
dim r as range
dim ws as worksheet
for each ws in worksheets
  for each r in ws.usedrange
    if r.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 128, 0) Then
        r = r.offset(0,-1)
     end if
  next r
next ws
```